# vagrant не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: cmd, vagrant

Установил Vagrant.При выполнении команды vagrant up консоль выдает "vagrant не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом" в переменной path указан путь "C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin"

Comment: Комп перезагружали?

Comment: неоднократно(((

Comment: Значит неправильно прописали, проверьте, что нет пробелов, что стоит точка с запятой и т.д.

Comment: Проверил. пробелов нет.точка с запятой стоит перед  C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin